# Sum values in alternating rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have numerical values of two types in alternating rows. Therefore, the value of one type is always on either odd or even rows and vice-versa. See below for an example

```
ROW # | VALUE // TYPE

    1 | COLUMN HEADERS
    2 |     6 // type a
    3 |   289 // type b
    4 |   391 // type a
    5 | 1,582 // type b
    6 |     9 // type a
    7 |   804 // type b
```

I would like to sum each set of values in the simplest way possible. I made a bunch of attempts, but none of them worked. Below is one of the attempts:

```
=SUMIF(G$2:G$999999, ISODD(ROW()),G$2:G$999999)
```

I believe I understand why this one does not work. The criteria is `ISODD(ROW())`, which evaluates to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and is not equivalent to the numerical values.

Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

For the odd rows

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10, MOD(ROW(A1:A10)+0, 2))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10, MOD(ROW(A2:A10)+1, 2))
```

for the even rows.

Comment: after mulling over this, i understand whats going on now. the 2nd argument of `sumproduct` is being used to generate either `0` or `1` in order to determine which value to multiply/add or not. is the `+0` even necessary?

Comment: why wouldnt something like this work: `=SUMPRODUCT(G$2:G$999999,IF(ISODD(ROW(G$2:G$999999)),1,0))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(G$2:G$999999,IF(ISODD(ROW()),1,0))` i believe i tried something like this last night, but keep getting `VALUE` errors